# What do you say when someone one points at you and says there it is and you never met them before and it wasn't you

Tags: responses

What do say when someone one just walks up to you and points and says there it is and you never met them before and it wasn't you?

Comment: "Eat your heart out!"

Comment: "I think you are confusing me with somebody else" - but this isn't really a language question.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say, "There **you** are"?